# Using DataItem to communicate between react native app and Wear OS app

Tags: android, react-native, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am currently working on a Wear OS app as an extension of a React Native app. I would like to communicate between the two using a something like DataItems. But I have no idea how to do this and if this is at all possible. The problem is that there is very little information on the internet. Does someone have experience doing this? Where should I look for information? Thanks!